# Is centering an element vertically using flexbox a good practice?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've read a few times that if you need to center an element vertically you can use flexbox. Is this really a good practice? Or is there a better way to do this without flexbox?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Flexbox is the latest and the most improved styling version and it. is an absolute yes to your. question . However it is not the only way , it is possible to use. . and margins and many more but Flexbox is by far the best way that could rather. be difficult to understand in the beginning .  Reffer to this amazing. document which. even i still sometime go back to .

https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/flexbox/